# Cambiar imagen por defecto DataGridView Image column C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hola buenas como indico en el titulo lo que quiero es quitar la imagen con la X, no he encontrado nada en internet que me sirva ni se me ocurre nada alguien sabe como cambiar esa imagen por defecto por otra que yo indique?

Me refiero a la imagen de la X la cual se crea cuando se crea una nueva row automaticamente

Comment: Necesitamos algun dato mas: como está definida la columna, y tal vez una captura de a que te refieres.

Comment: Es un datagridview imagecolumn y me refiero a la imagen default que sale que es un aspa roja, basicamente cambiar esa imagen por mia

Comment: No estoy seguro de si te refieres a esto. En la columna tienes la propiedad `DefaultCellStyle.NullValue` donde si no me equivoco puedes asignar la imagen cuando el valor de la columna es null. Como sigues sin decirme si la columna la estas definiendo en el designer o por código, no puedo darte mas información.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Gracias por hacerme notar que había malinterpretado la pregunta, para asignar el valor por defecto, solo bastaría asignar la imágen correspondiente a la propiedad `NullValue`

En el caso de tener un `DataGridView` que posea 2 `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` y 1 `DataGridViewImageColumn`

```
dataGridView1.Columns[2].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Properties.Resources.image01;
```

De más está decirlo, que es una propiedad que podes asignar antes de agregar el objeto de tipo `DataGridViewImageColumn` al `DataGridView` en cuestión

```
DataGridViewImageColumn a = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
a.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = Properties.Resources.descarga;
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(a);
```

Sin embargo, sería interesante que leas la documentación de **[DataGridViewImageColumn](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewimagecolumn?view=netframework-4.7.2)**, para que puedas aplicar esto de manera más precisa a tus problemas..

Comment: No. El OP se refiere (si no me equivoco) a la imagen por defecto cuando el valor de la columna es `null`. Tu respuesta se refiere a poner una imagen cuando si tiene valor.

Comment: Si me referia a eso

Comment: @DanielAparicio ahí modifique la respuesta, gracias por avisarme Pikoh!